# Unable to use Float module in Utop

Tags: module, ocaml, utop

I'm trying to use the Float Module in Utop, however whenever I try to open it in Utop by doing this :

```
open Float;;
Error: Unbound module Float
```

I get this error

I'm using OCaml version 4.05.0, Utop version 2.2.0 (Utop is using 4.05.0 as well, just in case)

Anyway to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What version of OCaml are you using?

Comment: @PatJ Sorry, forgot to add the versions. They're now in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Float` module was added in OCaml in version `4.07.0`. So it is not available to your version.

You can either upgrade your version (if you are using opam it's fairly easy) or do without.

Comment: I've been trying to find how to update OCaml using opam, didn't find anything. Could you provide a link or the command lines to do it please?

Comment: opam switch create 4.07.0 ; then eval $(opam env); then opam install utop